# How to disable automatic scaling in UIL (universal image loader)?

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

Probably it sounds ridiculous, but is there a way to disable to automatic scaling option in UIL (universal image loader library)? And how to do that?

Comment: see https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Display-Options and check `.imageScaleType()` method on `DisplayOption`

Comment: i've tried with ImageScaleType.NONE / EXACTLY / NONE_SAFE, but the image stays the same. Both width and height for my ImageView are set to wrap_content. It happens that I need the image exactly as it is, without scaling...